# How to remove vscode completely from ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu-20.04

I have tried **sudo snap remove code** it's just uninstalled vscode, I'm unable to use **autoremove** option for snap. I want to completely remove vscode from my system and reinstall it.

Answer (score 10):

Please try

```
sudo snap remove code
```

then

```
cd ~ && rm -rf .vscode && rm -rf .config/Code
```

This will remove your settings and then you can do a clean install

Answer (score 2):

To uninstall vscode use

```
sudo apt purge code
```

after uninstalling vscode use following command to remove the menu items

```
sudo apt autoremove
```

Comment: sudo apt doesn't work for the applications downloaded from snap store. I have installed it from snap store.

Answer (score 1):

first run

> sudo apt remove --autoremove code

if run `apt update` you look

> Hit:5 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease

you need remove repository on`/etc/apt/sources.list.d` the file `vscode.list`

> sudo rm -f /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list

run `apt update` and no more repository :)